# Regular expression for "mm-dd-yy" date format not finding any match in python

Tags: python, regex, datetime

I am reading a .csv file with 5 columns - C1, C2, C3, C4, C5.

C4 contains dates, phone numbers, text, etc.

Now, I am trying to write a regular expression to find dates with `mm-dd-yy` format in C4 and output the results to a text file. However, my code is not outputting anything to the file. I know there are dates with that date format in my input file, but something seems wrong. Any suggestions ?

**My Code:**

```
import re

inputfile = open("train.csv", 'r')
outputfile = open("sample.txt",'w')
for line in inputfile:
    x = re.findall('.*?^([0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9])$.*', line)
    if len(x) != 0:
        print >> outputfile, x
```

**Sample train.csv file format:**

```
sen_id  word_id type        before      after
1       0       text        On          On
1       1       date        12/2/12     december twelve two thousand twelve
1       2       text        there       there
2       0       text        he          he
2       1       text        was         was
2       2       text        born        born
2       3       date        Jan-12      january two thousand twelve
```

Comment: Remove `.*?^` and `$.*`

Comment: Dude.. regex eagle..!

Comment: as said by @WiktorStribiżew, also the code can be streamlined `r'(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2})'` although you probably want to have further check for validity of date.

Comment: Thanks. But, how do I search for the regex only on column4 ?

Comment: @user8929822 use the csv module to read your csv file.

Comment: `r'[0-9][0-9]?[-/][0-9][0-9]?[-/][0-9][0-9]'` or `r'\d{1,2}[-/]\d{1,2}[-/]\d{2}'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you avoid using regular expressions for this and instead attempt to convert each entry into a valid `datetime` object. If the conversion fails, you then know it is not in the correct format. This would then also cope correctly with all the various `30` or `31` type month length issues. Secondly, it can be extended easily to spot your second date format of `Jan-12`:

```
from datetime import datetime
import csv

with open('train.csv', 'rb') as f_input, open('sample.txt', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    header = next(csv_input)

    for row in csv_input:
        for date_format in ['%m/%d/%y', '%b-%y']:
            try:
                converted = datetime.strptime(row[3], date_format)
                csv_output.writerow([row[0], row[1], converted.strftime(date_format)])
            except ValueError:
                pass
```

Giving you two entries for your data as follows:

```
1,1,12/02/12
2,3,Jan-12
```

Comment: This looks like a better approach. However, I want to output the same date

 formatting from the input file to the output file. i.e. the output file should 

contain:

12/2/12

Jan-12

Comment: If you want to keep the original format, use `f_output.write("{}\n".format(row[3]))`

Comment: So, it's outputting the following dates:

12/2/12
12/02/12

How can I tell it to output 12/02/12 and not 12/2/12 ?

Comment: That's why my previous approach is better. It lets you make sure all dates have the same format. You could use the current `date_format` which would give you the leading `0`. This would also fix `feb-13` to `Feb-13` for example.

Comment: Got it. Also, I want to output the 1st and 2nd column values for each instance of the 3rd column. Not sure how I would do that ?

Comment: It sounds like you want CSV style output too?

Comment: Yes, I want to output column 1,2 & 4. 

do I just do - f_output.write("{}\n".row[0], rows[1],format(row[3]))

Comment: It would be better to just write it as CSV using `writerow()`.

Comment: can I use writerow() to write to .txt file instead ?

Comment: The name of the file does not matter, you need to have a `csv.writer()` though. I have updated the script to show you how.

Comment: wow, really good solution Martin!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex to match the date, but if you plan to do any further processing with it it might be a good idea to use the `datetime` module instead. I changed your code up in a way that it should run, using the `csv` and `re` modules.

Other quality of life things: When opening files, use `with` to declare them. It takes care of opening and closing the filestream, which can be a headache otherwise.

The `csv` module also separates rows into entry lists, which is why `row[3]` gets the 4th column without needing to regex for it.

```
import csv
import re

date_matcher = re.compile(r'(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2})')
with open("sample.txt",'w') as output_file, open("train.csv", 'r') as input_file:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in reader:
        for match in date_matcher.finditer(row[3]):
            output_file.write(match.group(0))
```

edit: Changed `match` to `finditer`, did not realise there would be multiple dates in the fourth column.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. However, I am receiving the following error.

NameError: name 'match_object' is not defined

Comment: Forgot to refactor it properly, it should have just been `match`

Answer (score 1):

Use regex `\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}` as follows in your code:

**code:**

```
x = re.findall('\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}', line)
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. However, how do I perform the search on just column4 ?

Comment: Its csv file so you can split line by comma and instead of entire line you can use specific column. Can you provide sample csv in question too ?

Comment: sorry, I have included the sample csv format in the question. it's a bit tricky aligning the columns.

Answer (score 0):

The devil is in the detail in this case.

Considering it's late to answer the op, my answer is here to who may seek a similar answer.

You gave a string literal instead of a regular expression to the `re.findall()` method.
In Python a lower case `r` denotes a regular expression, like in:
`'string_literal'` -> `r'string_as_regex'`.

So (without validating your regex, since this objection is true for any) you could use either:

```py
x = re.findall(r'.*?^([0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9])$.*', line)
```

OR compile the regex first and then use it like:

```py
rx = re.compile('regex expression')
match = rx.findall(line)
```

as you can see it here: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.compile

Note: this will return a list of the matching strings (0-n) and you're better filtering for empty strings in the list returned by `re.findall()`.

Now, to give an actual answer to your question for "how do I search for the regex only on column4?" - you actually don't.
When you are reading a flat-file - as you did - you get strings for each 'line' therefore there are no actual "columns". You could use a CSV reader to get the columns separately if you need that.

Though, there're ways to write regular expressions which will consider the "columns" - sort of. It's tricky and fragile. In your regex:

- use `\s` for any whitespace which may be present as the separator
  between columns, `\s+` for one or more (tabs may be represented as
  series of spaces)
- use grouping `(...)` around sections
- use the `|` (OR) operator for matching if necessary, like in `[0-9]{4}(-|/)[0-9]{2}` will match both `2019-08` and `2019/08`

So consider this Python regex:

```py
((([0-9])\s+){2}([a-z]{4})\s+){1}([0-9]{2}(/|-)[0-9]{1,2}(/|-)[0-9]{2})
```

And with it this code example (you can run it straight in a Python console):

```py
import re

inp = ['sen_id  word_id type    before  after', 
    '1   0   text    On  On', 
    '1   1   date    12/2/12 december twelve two thousand twelve', 
    '2   1   date    12-2-12 december twelve two thousand twelve', 
    '3  1   date    12-2-12 december twelve two thousand twelve', 
    '1   2   text    there   there', '2   0   text    he  he',]

rx = re.compile('((([0-9])\s+){2}([a-z]{4})\s+){1}([0-9]{2}(/|-)[0-9]{1,2}(/|-)[0-9]{2})')

for line in inp:
    hit = rx.findall(line)
    hit[0] if hit else None

for line in inp:
    hit = rx.match(line)
    hit.groups() if hit else None

for line in inp:
    hit = rx.search(line)
    hit.groups() if hit else None
```

Note that the data is slightly different from your example, to demonstrate the conditional matching (`|`) and the substitution of the white spaces (`\s`)

each for loop will return the same output, for each line where it find matches returns a tuple of 7 comma separated values, each value is for a group (`(...)`) in the regex:

```
('1   1   date    ', '1   ', '1', 'date', '12/2/12', '/', '/')
('2   1   date    ', '1   ', '1', 'date', '12-2-12', '-', '-')
('3  1   date    ', '1   ', '1', 'date', '12-2-12', '-', '-')
```

every fifth group (index 4) is the value you were looking for.

using the same data and the same compiled regex from above (remember this is written to run in a Python console):

```py
for line in inp:
    hit = rx.findall(line)
    hit[0][4] if hit else None

for line in inp:
    hit = rx.match(line)
    hit.group(5) if hit else None

for line in inp:
    hit = rx.search(line)
    hit.group(5) if hit else None
```

each for loop will return:

```
'12/2/12'
'12-2-12'
'12-2-12'
```

That's it.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

try this, for your regex

```
x = re.findall('([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})', line)
```

Comment: I know couldn't give comments so only given answer.

Comment: After my answer only "user8929822" he added more csv details.